# Rails getting data from nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, nested-attributes

I have three models:

**data_set.rb**

```
class DataSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :browse_options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :browse_options, allow_destroy: true 
end
```

**browse_option.rb**

```
class BrowseOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :data_set
  has_many :browse_option_datas
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :browse_option_datas, allow_destroy: true 
end
```

**browse_option_data.rb**

```
class BrowseOptionData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :browse_options

  has_one :tradesman
end
```

I want to be able to display all the tradesman associated with a data set in the data set view with no duplicates. Is there a way I can use the joins method to do this in the controller? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually achieve this by setting up `has_many through` relationships between your models. There are [great docs on this topic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

```
class DataSet
  has_many :browse_options
  has_many :browse_option_datas, :through => :browse_options
  has_many :tradesmen, :through => :browse_option_datas
end

class BrowseOption
  belongs_to :data_set
  has_many :browse_option_datas
end

class BrowseOptionData
  belongs_to :browse_options
  belongs_to :tradesman
end

class Tradesman
  has_many :browse_options_data
end
```

**Edit:** After some [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72230/discussion-between-thechamp-and-mikeholford) we also realised the relationships between `Tradesman` & `BrowseOptionData` needed some fixing.

Now, in your **controller**, you can call:

```
@data_set = DataSet.first
@tradesmen = @data_set.tradesmen # .uniq if you don't want any duplicates
```